# Add product short description in cart Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add short product description to cart: I do add it to the cart but whats weird that it does not show on checkout page, as my cart is in the header. Any ideas or other solutions are very helpful thanks in advance

```
function excerpt_in_cart() {

$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 80);
return '<br><p class="shortDescription">' . $excerpt .'...' . '</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'excerpt_in_cart', 40 );
```

When on checkout page it does not show this part from the code ' . $excerpt .' p shows up with the class just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function excerpt_in_cart($cart_item_html, $product_data) {
global $_product;

$excerpt = get_the_excerpt($product_data['product_id']);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 80);

echo $cart_item_html . '<br><p class="shortDescription">' . $excerpt . '...' . '</p>';
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'excerpt_in_cart', 40, 2);
```

First of all `woocommerce_cart_item_name` hook is filter hook not the action hook.

Most of the things you did correctly few minor issues are

- You have to use add_filter with `woocommerce_cart_item_name` hook.
- Overwrote the woocommerce created html instead of concatenate your excerpt.
- Missed to handle each cart item's excerpt by using their product ID.

---

**Additional info:**

This is from wordpress core file plugin.php

```
function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
    return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
}
```

function `add_action` is just the wrapper function of `add_filter`.